# How can I access an central ResourceBundle in Wicket

Tags: java, properties, resources, wicket, resourcebundle

The Internationalization of Wicket is realized with many little Properties-Files in the same folders like there html-Files.

My architekture ist one Properties-File in the webapp-Folder or an other unique Folder.

My favorite Example:
src/java/main/net/kog/WicketApplikation.java:

```
getResourceSettings().getResourceFinders().add(
       new WebApplicationPath(getServletContext(), "resource"));
BundleStringResourceLoader bundle = new BundleStringResourceLoader("text.properties");
getResourceSettings().getStringResourceLoaders().add(bundle);
// Test
String str = bundle.loadStringResource(net.kog.resource.Text.class, "login.noscript", Locale.getDefault(), null, null);
System.out.println(str);
```

Markup:

```
<div wicket:id="login.noscript" id="js"/>
```

But whereever I locate the File text.properties the ResourceBundle not found, no String was returned.
tried Locations:

- src/main/webapp
- src/main/webapp/resource
- src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/resource
- src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/resource
- src/main/resources
- src/main/resources/resource
- src/main/resources/net/kog/resource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **Solution:**

1. First, the answer of martin-g has given the right direktion. The properties-File have to be the same name like the Application-class ("WicketApplication.properties").
2. Second, very useful was to change the debuglevel in Wicket (src\main\resources\log4j2.xml) from LEVEL.INFO to LEVEL.DEBUG. There was a many Information about the URL (Path) which Wicket has tried to loaded.
3. Third, I make the way to access my properties-File shorter, because I delete IsoPropertiesFilePropertiesLoader (ISO-8859 formated Properties-Files) and XmlFilePropertiesLoader in net.kog.WicketApplication.init(). Code:

   ```
   List<IPropertiesLoader> propertiesLoader = 
           ((PropertiesFactory)getResourceSettings().getPropertiesFactory()).getPropertiesLoaders();
   getResourceSettings().getPropertiesFactory().clearCache();
   propertiesLoader.clear();
   propertiesLoader.add(new UtfPropertiesFilePropertiesLoader("properties", "utf-8"));
   ```

The full path of my UTF-8 properties-File is src/main/webapp/net/kog/WicketApplication.properties

Answer (score 2):

Please read http://wicket.apache.org/guide/guide/i18n.html for more information how to split or combine the resource bundles in your application.

Comment: This side I have read the last week again and again, and I have tried some ideas, but I find not the right infos. Which subpoint do you mean?

Comment: Put your i18n stuff in src/main/resources/net/kog/WicketApplikation.properties. Make sure it is copied in the final .jar/.war file next to WicketApplikation.class file. Then use Component#getSttring(someKey), ResourceModel, application.getREsourceSettings().getLocalizer().getString(...), etc.